# Is there a survey of the field of quantum automata?

Tags: reference-request, quantum-computing, automata-theory

I'm looking for a survey paper of the important concepts in the field of Quantum Automata. I've found [Quantum Automata Theory -- A Review](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221351451_Quantum_Automata_Theory_-_A_Review)
 by Hirvensalo, but it sounds too succinct to grasp the topic.
Is there a quite comprehensive survey on the topic of Quantum Automata?

Also, could you point me to the essential literature about the topic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check the recent survey by Ambainis and Yakaryilmaz: [Automata and Quantum Computing](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.01988). It is comprehensive and points the essential literature with some open questions.

Moreover, [here](http://publication.wikia.com/wiki/Quantum_automata) is a list of papers published on quantum automata until 2015.